# SharePoint Validation Uppercase Character

Tags: list, validation, sharepoint

So I'm basically trying to validate a column in my SharePoint list to have a Specific letter as the starting character of the field. I'm running into an issue with capitalization. I need the first character to be only uppercase. This is what I currently have but it is not validating for only uppercase. (67 is the ascii code for the letter "c"). Thank you!

```
CODE(MID([Column Name],1,1)=UPPER(67))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
=if(CODE(MID([Test],1,1))=67,true,false)
```

Or use JavaScript to validate `PreSaveAction`

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31330.sharepoint-using-presaveaction-function-on-custom-list-forms.aspx